# pyenv version still pointing to old install

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I am on MacOS and recently switched from pyenv 1.2.26 to pyenv 2.0.1 using `brew upgrade`. I now seem to have conflicting pyenv versions on my machine and am not sure how to fix this. In `/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv`, I see version `2.0.1` installed only. However, when I run `pyenv --version`, I get the 1.2.26 version returned. There is also a `~/.pyenv` folder whose bin files all point to the old 1.2.26 version. How do I go about fixing this?
I tried `pyenv rehash` which was pointed to [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/849), but I think that's just for updating the shims.

Comment: hey! were you able to solve this issue? I'm also interested in knowing the solution!

Comment: Hey,  if I remember correctly I solved this by simply uninstalling everything (`brew uninstall  pyenv`, `rm -rf ~/.pyenv` and remove all related entries in your `.zshrc` file) and then reinstalling via the instructions mentioned here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation